# RSA Inverse Multiplication

Tags: rsa

I have $n,e$ and $c$, $p$ and $q$ are prime, but $q$ is the inverse multiplication of $e$ and $p$ so $$q = e^{-1} \bmod p$$

How can $i$ get $p$ and $q$ back?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. What is the origin of this question? What did you try to solve up to now?

Comment: I looked for some properties to make it, for sure there is some trick

Comment: Also, if you're referring to the standard CRT parameters, we have $dp = e^{-1} \bmod p$ and $qinv = q^{-1} \bmod p$.  Are you referring to one of them?

Comment: but i dont have no one of then, i dont have d, p and q

Comment: what do you have?

Comment: i have only n, e and c, but i cant do anything with this

Comment: @poncho: Are you sure your definition of $dp$ is correct? (you forgot the -1)

Comment: @j.p.: yes, you are correct...

Answer (score 1):

If $e$ is not too large, then it is easy.

The relation $q = e^{-1} \mod p$ can be rearranged to $qe = 1 + kp$ for some integer $k$; or in other words, $p/q \approx e / k$; that is, $p/q$ is extremely close to a simple rational, and that makes factorization easy.

Comment: Using the multiplier improvement to Fermat's method for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method#Multiplier_improvement

Comment: Mhh ok, but im a little bit confused, i dont have p and q, so should I go trial and error?

Comment: @billst: obviously, you could try various values of $k$ (and you know that $k < e$, so there's a limited number); just checking $q \approx \sqrt{ (k/e) N }$ for the various $k$ should recover the value $q$ fairly quickly

Comment: sorry, but I can write to you in private somewhere?